# Angular templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frontend

I'd like to know if this :

```
<field>
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <error>ERROR !!!</error>
</field>
```

is transformable into this :

```
<!-- field directive is transformed into div.field-container -->
<div class="field-container">
    <div class="field">
        <!-- input here -->
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="error">
        <!-- error directive is transformed into span -->
        <span>ERROR !!!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You will need to make use of ngShow or some other angular logic to control when you want the error to be displayed.

Comment: My question is not quite precise. The difficulty is to "rearrange" input and error elements in the field directive template. I don't know how to get siblings nodes and put separatly in different places. (I don't know if i'm clear !!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of angular directives to achieve that:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.directive('errorDirective', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<div class="error"><span>ERROR !!!</span></div>'
  };
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fLddpk75/

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive